# Break Out XML Field within Query

Tags: sql, xml

really hoping that someone can help.  This is probably nothing too new but just can't find the right answer.

I have a very simple SQL query that works totally fine;

```
SELECT
SecUser.Name, SecUser.Description,
SecUser.IsEnabled, SecUser.ExternalAuthProviderName,
SecUser.ExternalUserName, SecUser.Email, SecUser.XmlData

FROM
SecUser

ORDER BY
SecUser.Name
```

However, the final column is XmlData and is a combination of 4 fields.

```
<UserDetail>
 <TEXT1> "random text 1" </TEXT1>
 <TEXT2> "random text 2" </TEXT2>
 <TEXT3> "random text 3" </TEXT3>
 <TEXT4> "random text 4" </TEXT4>
 </UserDetail>
```

What I need help on is, how do I;

- break out the 4 bits of text between the tags into their own columns???

Any help would be REALLY appreciated but please note, I am a total newbie :(

I am now trying to add a WHERE clause to the code, which works really well;

However, the WHERE statement keeps giving an error of 'Invalid Column Name'?? I have tried many different things but can not seem to get it to filter with the WHERE???

```
SELECT Name, 
       Description,
       IsEnabled, 
       ExternalAuthProviderName,
       ExternalUserName, 
       Email, 
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/Text1[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS "SummaryGroup",
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/Text2[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS "SecurityGroup",
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/Text3[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS "Access",
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/Text4[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS "InsiderList"

FROM SecUser

WHERE   (UserDetail/Text1 = 'Management')

ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: I think the solution will depend on what kind & version of database you use.  MySql 5.x, MySql 8.x, Oracle 12g, MS SQL Server 2012, SqLite, PostgreSql, Teradata ?

Comment: Hi, it is just a SQL query within the system database for a dashboard report, hope that helps?

Comment: No, unfortunately that does not help. "SQL" is a query language used by all relational databases. The support for XML parsing varies greatly between the different products, so in order to get an answer that you can actually use, it's important that we know which DBMS product your "dashboard" is using. Otherwise you might get answers that you can't use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work in MSSQL/T-SQL, assuming `XmlData` has a type of `XML`

```
SELECT Name, 
       Description,
       IsEnabled, 
       ExternalAuthProviderName,
       ExternalUserName, 
       Email, 
       XmlData.value('UserDetail[1]/TEXT1[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS TEXT1,
       XmlData.value('UserDetail[1]/TEXT2[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS TEXT2,
       XmlData.value('UserDetail[1]/TEXT3[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS TEXT3,
       XmlData.value('UserDetail[1]/TEXT4[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS TEXT4
FROM SecUser
ORDER BY Name
```

If `XmlData` has a type of `VARCHAR`, then you will need to cast it as `XML`

```
SELECT Name, 
       Description,
       IsEnabled, 
       ExternalAuthProviderName,
       ExternalUserName, 
       Email, 
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/TEXT1[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS TEXT1,
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/TEXT2[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS TEXT2,
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/TEXT3[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS TEXT3,
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/TEXT4[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS TEXT4
FROM SecUser
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your speedy response, I just tried your answer but had the following error message;

Comment: "cannot find either "XmlData" or the user-defined function or aggregate "XmlData.Value" or the name is ambiguous"

Comment: Updated answer to account for "XmlData" being set to varchar instead of xml.  Try it now.

Comment: thanks, I have just tried and the Columns are now created but the data is not populating?

Comment: The node names (TEXT1, TEXT2, etc) are case sensitive, are you sure they are all caps?

Comment: FANTASTIC, no, they were not all caps, I changed and now it works!.... really big thank you for your very speedy response and solution!! :)

Comment: Hi, just a quick follow-up;

Comment: if I want to add a WHERE into the query code, how can I do this as at the moment I can not get this to work??

Comment: SELECT Name, 
       Description,
       IsEnabled, 
       ExternalAuthProviderName,
       ExternalUserName, 
       Email, 
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/Text1[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS "SummaryGroup",
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/Text2[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS "SecurityGroup",
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/Text3[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS "Access",
       CAST(XmlData AS XML).value('UserDetail[1]/Text4[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS "InsiderList"

FROM SecUser

WHERE   (UserDetail/Text1 = 'Management')

ORDER BY Name

Comment: I get the following error message for my WHERE clause  "invalid column name"

Comment: `WHERE Text1 = 'Management'`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that still gives me the error "invalid column name"??